# Time optimizing writing array into file in Python

Tags: python, file, optimization, time

I'm fairly new to python, so any idea is greatly appreciated!

I have a dictionary that contains a 2D numpy array 'rho' of 1572864×100 elements or more. I need to put it into a text or binary
file with .9e formatting and separeted by '\n'. It ends up ~3 GB. So far I came up with

```
if self.par["rho"].ndim == 2:
        for y in range(0,np.size(self.par["rho"],0)-1):
            print("\n".join(f"{d:.9e}" for d in self.par['rho'][y,:]), file=outfile)
```

How do I speed this up? Right now I'm at 265 s.

Comment: do you really need to put it into a text file? there are much more efficient ways of storing and reading large arrays.

Comment: Unfortunately I do. I'm working with an external tool called radmc3d that reads input txt or binary files

Comment: it seems that all you need is the numpy.savetxt function specifying the `fmt` argument: `fmt='%.9e'`. A complete call would be: `numpy.savetxt("mylargefile.txt", self.par["rho"], fmt="%.9e")`.

Comment: Btw: using your loop `for y in range(0,np.size(self.par["rho"],0)-1):` it seems like you are omitting the last line. is that intentional?

Comment: @dnalow ye, that last line was a mistake, thanks!

Comment: Just use the binary format, which is quite well documented (smaller files for the same precision and faster). The documentation is on page 172 of http://www.ita.uni-heidelberg.de/~dullemond/software/radmc-3d/radmc-3d_v0.41.pdf If you provide an complete example of writing a ascii file, it will be quite easy to show how to write an equivalent binary file.